# Using an object of a class in another class

Tags: c++, class, object

I have a class named Student which looks like this

```
class Student
{   string name;
    unsigned long int ID ;
    string email;
    unsigned short int year;
    public : 
         Student() // Constructor
         string getName(void);
         unsigned long int getID(void);
         string getEmail(void);
         unsigned short int getYear(void);   
{
```

and another class named eClass

```
class eClass
 {
     string eclass_name;
     Student* students[100];
     unsigned int student_count;
     public:
        eClass(string name)
        {
            student_count=0 ; 
            eclass_name = name  ; 
        }

        void add(Student& obj)
        {
            bool res = exists(Student obj);  ****
            if (res)
            {
            }
            else
            {
                students[student_count] = obj ;  **** 
                student_count++ ; 
            }
        }

        bool exists(Student &obj)
        {
            unsigned long int code = obj.getID(); ****
            bool flag = FALSE ;
            for (int i = 0 ; i<=student_count ; i++ )
            {
                unsigned long int st = students[i]->getID();
                if (code==st)
                {
                    flag = TRUE;
                }
            }
            return flag;
        }
    };
```

It basically creates an object which represents a lesson and then adds students to the lesson via add() after it checks that the student does not already belong to the lesson.

I am getting an error at the lines I've marked with ****. 
Could someone help me what's going wrong...I'm not pretty sure I've understood how to use an object of a class in another one.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't  correct:

```
       bool res = exists(Student obj);  // ****
```

It should look like this:

```
       bool res = exists(obj);  // ****
```

`obj` is the argument to the function (of type `Student`) that can be used inside the function.  On this line, you are using that argument to pass it to another function.

Comment: Also `Student* students[100];` should be `Student students[100];`, or, if not, proper memory allocation has to be done; `students[student_count] = obj` won't compile.

Comment: @vsoftco you can do `Student* students[100]`, just use `Students[student_count] = new student()`, every time you want to add an object. That way you don't allocate all of them at once. Just the ones you have.

Comment: @lciamp You suggest using Students[student_count] = new student() every time I want to add an object of type student to the Students table?

Comment: @Alice1nw0 You have to decide whether you want to use an array of pointers or not.  For a simple example it's easier to avoid them and do as vsoftco has suggested - do without them and use an array of objects instead of an array of pointers to objects.

Comment: The guidelines we were given suggest using  Student* students[500];... I can't really understand what this is supposed to mean...

Comment: That is an array of size 500 of pointers to `Student` objects.

Comment: @AnonMail And something last....In that case how could I allocate memory dynamically for *students[500]. Obviously using the new command , but what would be the proper syntax?

Comment: For `Student * students[100]`, just make sure the array of pointers is initialized to 0 or `nullptr`.  Then for each `Student` you want ot add to the array do: `students[i] = new student();` where `i` is the index to the ith element of the array.

Comment: @AnonMail How should that work? I mean how can I initialize my array of pointers to 0 or nullptr before even allocating memory for it?

Comment: @Alice1nw0 you can initialize to null like this: `Student* students[100] = {};` then you have to use `students[studentNum] = new student();` you have an array of pointers, you need to use new to create objects for those pointers to point at.